# Найти protected метод после наследования в c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класс ApplicationClass с методом CustomMethod:

```
public class ApplicationClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    protected void CustomMethod()
    {
        //любой код
    }
}
```

От него наследуется NewClass:

```
public class NewClass : ApplicationClass 
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        ApplicationController.ScriptAdd(this);
    }
}
```

NewClass при создании добавляет себя в массив scriptArr класса ApplicationController.
А ScriptCustomMethod вызывает необходимые методы по требованию:

```
public class ApplicationController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static MonoBehaviour[] scriptArr;

    public static void ScriptAdd(MonoBehaviour script)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref scriptArr, scriptArr?.Length + 1 ?? 1);
        scriptArr[scriptArr.Length - 1] = script;
    }

    public static void ScriptCustomMethod(string methodName, object[] arg)
    {
        if (scriptArr == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < scriptArr.Length; i++)
        {
            var dynMethod = scriptArr[i].GetType().GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            dynMethod?.Invoke(scriptArr[i], arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно вызвать CustomMethod из NewClass используя ScriptCustomMethod:

```
private void Update()
{
    ApplicationController.ScriptCustomMethod("CustomMethod", new object[] { });
}
```

Но найти его и вызвать используя различные комбинации BindingFlags не получается.
Если CustomMethod переместить из ApplicationClass в NewClass, то вышеприведенный код работает.

Comment: Если вы в `newClass` вызываете метод `customMethod()`, то он работает?

Comment: Да, если CustomMethod() разместить в NewClass, то его вызов работает.

Comment: Ну тогда пишите `new NewClass().CustomMethod();`, главное чтобы классы были под одним `namesapace`ом. Либо (если можно) сделать метод статичным, и вызывать так: `NewClass.CustomMethod();`

Comment: Сделать метод статичным не вариант. Так же как и создавать новый экземпляр класса. У меня ScriptCustomMethod специально сделан, чтобы вызывать методы из любого класса через их текстовое имя. Нужен вариант, чтобы обращаться к наследуемому методу, через его имя и никак иначе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было объявить:

```
private static ApplicationClass[] scriptArr;
```

Вместо:

```
private static MonoBehaviour[] scriptArr;
```